# Как сделать, чтобы круг был полностью виден сразу, а не попеременно? Круговой таймер на чистом css

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы серый круг, который находится в центре, был полностью виден сразу, а не так, как сейчас. Сейчас получается, что сначала загружается одна половина, а потом другая.
Это круговой таймер на чистом css

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    /*z-index: 1*/
}

.circe {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid gray;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.circe_r{
    margin-top: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-left: 3px solid gray;
}

.timer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.timer:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
    background-color: #fff;
    animation: mask_left 10s steps(1, end) forwards;
}

.timer:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: #BA628C;
    animation: mask_right 10s steps(1, end) forwards;
}

.timer__line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    animation: line 10s linear forwards;
}

.timer__line:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #BA628C;
}

.timer__body {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    border: 30px solid white;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 4;
}




.timer__counter {
    animation: counter 10s steps(9, end) forwards;
}

.timer__counter span {
    font-size: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    height: 120px;
}

@keyframes counter {
    0% {}

    100% {
        transform: translate(5px, -1080px);
    }
}

@keyframes line {
    0% {}

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes line {
    0% {}

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes mask_left {
    0% {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    50%,
    100% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

@keyframes mask_right {
    0% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    50%,
    100% {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="circe"></div>
        
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="timer">
        <div class="timer__line"></div>
        <div class="timer__body">
            <div class="timer__counter">
                <span>1</span>
                <span>2</span>
                <span>3</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>5</span>
                <span>6</span>
                <span>7</span>
                <span>8</span>
                <span>9</span>
                <span>10</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем, вот, что я сделал....

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.position {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
}

.circe {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid gray;
    z-index: 1;
}

.circe_right {
    width: 90px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 3px solid gray;
    border-radius: 100% 0 0 100% / 50% 0 0 50%;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 7;
    border-right: 0;
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    /* Opera */
    animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.timer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.timer:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
    background-color: #fff;
    animation: mask_left 10s steps(1, end) forwards;
}

.timer:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: #BA628C;
    animation: mask_right 10s steps(1, end) forwards;
}

.timer__line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    animation: line 10s linear forwards;
}

.timer__line:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #BA628C;
}

.timer__body {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    border: 30px solid white;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 4;
}




.timer__counter {
    animation: counter 10s steps(9, end) forwards;
}

.timer__counter span {
    font-size: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    height: 120px;
}

@keyframes counter {
    0% {}

    100% {
        transform: translate(5px, -1080px);
    }
}

@keyframes line {
    0% {}

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    to {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

@keyframes line {
    0% {}

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes mask_left {
    0% {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    50%,
    100% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

@keyframes mask_right {
    0% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    50%,
    100% {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="circe_right position"></div>
    <div class="circe position">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="timer">
        <div class="timer__line"></div>
        <div class="timer__body">
            <div class="timer__counter">
                <span>1</span>
                <span>2</span>
                <span>3</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>5</span>
                <span>6</span>
                <span>7</span>
                <span>8</span>
                <span>9</span>
                <span>10</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```